# can an android application play both music and navigation promt in same time?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to implement an app which continuously receives audio data and play it using AudioTrack. My app receives media data and navigation prompts at the same time. can these audios play together with the help of AudioManager service ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can play two (or more) AudioTracks at once. You can easily accomplish that using multiple AudioTrack instances.